# Can I run ode45 backwards in time?

Tags: matlab, ode

I use ode45 to solve differential equations but the tspan always has to be such that the system runs forward in time. Can I make ode45 run the system backwards to negative t?

The specific problem I have uses a rising exponential function i.e a*exp(at) from t=-infinity to t=0 and the function is zero for all t>0. As you can see, it isn't possibly to translate this function and use the interval t=0 to t=infinity in my problems. So, I would like ode45 to work in negative t.

Thank you!

EDIT: After some thinking, I realize that my question is phrased badly and I had a poor understanding too so let me restate it here.

My ODEs are of the form x'=f(t)x, where f(t)=a*exp(at) from -infinity to 0. The system starts with some intial conditions at t=-infinity. ode45 on the other hand requires tspan to be positive and also requires the initial conditions at t=0. So how can I change both these criteria?

Thank you :)

Comment: Why not substitute `-t` with a new time variable, say `s`, and obtain a new differential equation for `s`, solve it for `s` and then substitute `t` back into the solution?

Comment: No, you see that won't work for the function I have shown. a*exp(-as) from 0 to infinity is not the same as a*exp(at) from -infinity to 0. I don't think it's possible to "translate" this function to the positive t interval.

Comment: but a*exp(-as) from infinity to 0 is the same as a*exp(at) from -infinity to 0

Comment: Hi Rasman,
So, what would tspan be? [infinty:0]? I tried this with ode45. I tried just [2:0] and it gave me an error. What we are trying is essentially trying to run backward in time, isn't it? Unfortunately, it didn't work so could you suggest an alternative?

Comment: not sure if i'm thinking straight, but if you substitute t over [-inf, 0] with s = (-1/t) for s = [0, inf], does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a backwards linspace for generating your t.

For the forward direction (t), use something like t = 0:0.1:2. 
For the reverse direction (rt), use something like rt = 2:0-.1:0.

Comment: The reverse case should be `rt = 2:-0.1:0`.